# How can I check Marshmallow's permission in android wear?

Tags: android, permissions, wear-os, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am working with Marshmallow's Permission in android Wear. I got reference from developer site for permission request in Android wear.

I have well experienced with handset Permission request. But I still confuse How can I use in Android wear?

I referred following link http://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html#aic

I imagine that there is a same functionality of Permission request as handset.

Am I right?

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. :^) By and large, it works the same on the watch as on a handheld - at this level, they're both just Android Marshmallow. The dialog presented to the user is different, of course, but the API is identical.

[image]

Edit: it's also worth checking out [the doc page on Wear permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html), if you haven't already. There are some good details there.